# Write the function residue l n which calculates the residue of n by l by making an iterative calculation

Tags: ocaml

I want to write the function **residue l n** which calculates the residue of n by l by making an iterative calculation starting with n and  using the items in the list in order. The calculation is as follows:
-initially the residue is the value of n
-each element e of l (taken in the order of the list) changes the residue in the following way:
if e and the residue are of the same parity (both even or both odd) then the new residue is the sum of r and e, otherwise it is the difference between r and e (r-e).
-the last residue is the result of the game.
Example: residu [1;3] 7 returns 5 as a result of the following calculations:

```
7 + 1 (same parity +) = 8
8 - 3 (parité différente -) = 5
```

This is my code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
let rec residue l n =
  if l = [] then 
    0 
  else if (List.hd l mod 2 <> 0 && n mod 2 <> 0) || 
          (List.hd l mod 2 == 0 && n mod 2 == 0) then  
    List.hd l + residue (List.tl l) (List.hd l + n) 
  else 
    n - List.hd l - residue (List.tl l) (n - List.hd l);;

residu [1;3] 7;;
- : int = 6 (The correct result should be 5)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my stab at it.

```
let rec residue l n =
  let parity a b =
    ((a mod 2 <> 0) && (b mod 2 <> 0)) ||
    ((a mod 2 == 0) && (b mod 2 == 0)) 
  in
  match l, n with
    | [], n -> n
    | (x::xs), n -> if parity x n then residue xs (n+x) else residue xs (n-x)
```

Hope it helps for figuring out the problem.

Comment: `if cond then true else false` is the same as `cond`